# How can I add Auth0 as IdP into ADFS?

Tags: saml, adfs, auth0

I've asked this question on Auth0 community but wanted to ask in here also... https://community.auth0.com/t/how-can-i-add-auth0-as-idp-into-adfs/16868

I want to use Auth0 as an IdP for my application. So here is the flow:
Web Application --> ADFS --> Auth0 --> Social

I’ve red [this link](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-idp-generic) and did whatever it says; in order to add Auth0 as a Claims Provider into ADFS I’ve used the SAML Metadata URL. As a result I can now select Auth0 as IdP (or CP in ADFS terms) on ADFS login page and it redirects user to log in on Auth0. And client can authenticate on Auth0 with no doubt. But, when ADFS receives the HTTP POST SAML response from Auth0 it throws an error “MSIS0050: SAML Response does not match SAML request.”. And thus, client cannot login to web app.

Here are the details of the exception:
Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name:
Saml

Relying Party:

Exception details:
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.UnsupportedSamlResponseException: MSIS0050: SAML Response does not match SAML request. Request ID: id-2252c816-02de-423c-b518-703cbfd26055, response InResponseTo:
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.GetSecurityTokenFromSignInResponse(ProtocolContext context)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

So, What can be the problem here? Can you please help me on this?

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-with-social-logins-958aa8b327b7 If no joy, please publish the AuthN request and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault. For ADFS integration, on Auth0, selection of SAML2 integration medium was a bad idea. I just selected ADFS and it's working now. Thank you.